# Отслеживание вступлений в приватный канал

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Есть телеграм бот который имеет права администратора в нескольких приватных каналах. Основная его задача - генерировать ссылки (приглашения) в каналы. Но потом нужно отслеживать вступления в канал по сгенерированным ссылкам или вообще как то получать данные о количестве вступлений по сгенерированным ссылкам чтобы вести статистику. Как возможно сделать такой функционал?